# Views Better exposed filter, input required

Tags: 8, views

In which hook_ of the views.api can i hide the results if no exposed inputfilter is selected.

I tried:

hook_views_query_alter($view, $query) {

```
if($view->getExposedInput() ...) {
 // Do not show any results, make clear no results should be shown..
}
```

Or

```
hook_views_pre_render($view) {
    if($view->getExposedInput() ...) {
      $view->result = array();
      // But pager still shown and $view->getPager()->destroy() gives error.
      // Also feels wrong, query should not be executed.
    }
}
```

Any suggestions, solutions, .... Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by adding condition which yields no result.

```
hook_views_query_alter($view, $query) {
    // Don't show any result if exposed filter empty.
    $exposed_input = $view->getExposedInput();
    if(!isset($exposed_input['field_partner_address_country_code']) || $exposed_input['field_partner_address_country_code'] == 'All') {
      $query->addWhere(NULL, 'node_field_data.nid', 0);
    }
}
```